# clear variables on parallel kernel

Tags: parallelization, assignment

**Short question**: what is the proper way to clear a variable on a given kernel ? AND how can I ensure that the memory will indeed be freed subsequently ?

**Full question**. Let me elaborate this question with the following experiment in a fresh session.

```
kernel = ParallelEvaluate[$KernelID] (* launch sub kernels *)
bytesToMo[b_] := Round[b/1024.^2, .1];
memoryStatus := TableForm[Join[
    {{"FrontEnd", bytesToMo@MemoryInUse[$FrontEnd]},
    {$KernelID, bytesToMo@MemoryInUse[]}},
ParallelEvaluate[{$KernelID, bytesToMo@MemoryInUse[]}]],
TableHeadings -> {None, {"Kernel", "Memory in Mo"}}
];
Row[{
   memoryStatus, (* initial state *)
   "\t\[Rule]\t",
   ParallelEvaluate[
      If[$KernelID == kernel[[1]],x = Range[10^6]];
      If[$KernelID == kernel[[2]],y = Range[10^7]];
   ];
   memoryStatus
}]
```

As expected, x exists only on the first kernel (the first kernel memory increases) and y exists only on the second kernel (the second kernel memory increases more, as y is larger). One can check it for example like this:

```
checkXY := TableForm@Join[{{$KernelID, ReleaseHold[#]}}, 
   ParallelEvaluate[{$KernelID, ReleaseHold[#]}]] &[Hold[
        Length[x], Length[y]
   ]];
checkXY
```

Now to clear x and y, I parallelize a call to Clear:

```
ParallelEvaluate[Clear[x, y]]; Column[{checkXY, memoryStatus}]
```

Here is the overall output (sorry, as this is my first post, they don't let me put more than 2 images so I had to collect them in one):

[image: output when it's ok]

Well, it works right ? The variables have been cleared and the memory is free... Well, not quite. Because If I run the whole thing one more time, the variables will be cleared, but the memory will not be freed anymore.

Here is the overall output of the second run:

[image: output with memory not freed at the end]

The only solution I found is to share the unset symbol from the Master Kernel, which then effectively erases the memory in all kernels.

```
Clear[x, y]
SetSharedVariable[x, y];
UnsetShared[x, y];
memoryStatus
```

My questions are:

1. Why is Clear[x,y] working the first time, but not subsequently ?
2. If Clear is not the right way, what is the proper way to unset a symbol in a given kernel ? The SetShared/Unset hack does not sound right to me (what if each kernel has a different x but I only want to get rid of a specific one)...

Thank you.

Comment: Sorry, I didn't read through your question, but this might help: since v10.4 for some reason `ParallelEvaluate` distributes definitions automatically.  Use `ParallelEvaluate[..., DistributedContexts -> None]` to prevent this.  IMO making ParallelEvaluate behave this way was a bad decision.

Comment: @Szabolcs: thanks for the info, but it does not seem to fix the problem. To ask my question differently: if you have a variable x defined on a subkernel, how would _you_ proceed to clean it ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I am answering the short form of your question, as you stated it in comments as well. I did not fully follow the rest of your question, so perhaps if this does not apply exactly, you could edit the question to present a minimal example.

---

You can operate on a variable on a specific subkernel by using [`ParallelEvaluate`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/ParallelEvaluate.html) together with that kernel's identifier.

For instance, let's load some parallel kernels, then create a symbol `x` on each of them and assign it a value:

```
LaunchKernels[]
(* Out: {"KernelObject"[1, "local"], "KernelObject"[2, "local"]} *)

ParallelEvaluate[x = 3]
(* Out: {3, 3} *)
```

Now let's clear `x` on the first subkernel only:

```
ParallelEvaluate[Clear[x], First@Kernels[]]
```

We can check that the value of `x` has been cleared on the first subkernel only, but is retained on the second one:

```
ParallelEvaluate[x]
(* Out: {x, 3} *)
```

Comment: thanks for your answer which recalls the proper syntax to clear a variable in a given subkernel. However, the point of my question is that it does not seem to reliably free the memory associated to that variable. When the objects start to represent 25% of the available RAM, an unreliable garbage collection after a clear is problematic.

Comment: I just edited the short question by adding "How can I ensure that the memory will indeed be freed subsequently ?"

Comment: @FrancoisVigneron I agree that it might be problematic, but I would caution you against changing the question mid-way; such behavior ("moving target questions") discourages answers, because one never know whether one might be wasting time answering the wrong question. You might be better off asking a new question entirely on that topic.

Comment: Thanks MarcoB. The precision of your answer made me clarify my own question. I validate your answer. I'll be posting a new one on the internal details of garbage collection.